# Pass gradients through min function in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a variable, say, `a` which has some gradient associated with it from some operations before. Then I have integers `b` and `c` which have no gradients. I want to compute the minimum of `a`, `b`, and `c`. MWE is as given below.

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad=True)  # As an example I have defined a leaf node here, in my program I have an actual variable with gradient
b = 5
c = 6
d = torch.min(torch.tensor([a, b, c]))  # d does not have gradient associated
```

How can I write this differently so that the gradient from `a` flows through to `d`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the line `d = torch.min(torch.tensor([a, b, c]))`

When you compute `torch.tensor([a, b, c])`, you create a new tensor that has no computational graph to the `a`, `b` or `c` tensors. For example:

```py
a = torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([5.])
c = torch.tensor([6.])
d = torch.tensor([a,b,c])
d.requires_grad
> False
```

The solution is to use the `min` function with the input tensors themselves.

```py
a = torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([5.])
c = torch.tensor([6.])
d = a.min(b).min(c)
d.requires_grad
> True
```

Note that the gradient of the `min` function is `1` for the min value and `0` for all other values. This means that you will lose gradient signal if the value you want to backprop through is not the min.

```py
a = torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([5.])
d = a.min(b)
d.backward()
a.grad
> tensor([1.])

a = torch.tensor([6.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([5.])
d = a.min(b)
d.backward()
a.grad
> tensor([0.])
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that 'b' and 'c' are also tensors with the same properties as your 'a' (just set the gradient to 'false').

Adjusted code looks like this:

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([5.], requires_grad=False)  # ensure b is a tensor
c = torch.tensor([6.], requires_grad=False)  # ensure c is also a tensor
d = torch.min(torch.cat((a, b, c)))  # concatenate tensors and compute minimum

# use backward to compute gradients with respect to a
d.backward()

print(a.grad)  # this should print the gradient of a
```

Comment: The minimum function is not differentiable, so there is no gradient of a.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. Yes, the minimum function is not differentiable everywhere (it's not differentiable if multiple inputs have the same value), but it's differentiable almost everywhere. Since, in this case, we don't have the same value in the multiple inputs, it's differentiable. If somehow the value of a is the minimum version of a, b and c, then there is no gradient of a, that's correct.