# Gradients for selection from array operation in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

This is a followup question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78072628/6997665). I have obtained a tensor, say, `d` with gradients. Now I have another tensor array, say `e` from which I need to pick the first `d` elements. MWE below.

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([5.])
c = torch.tensor([6.])
d = a.min(b).min(c)

e = torch.arange(10)
f = e[:d]  # Throws error "TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index"
```

Based on the answer [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/typeerror-only-integer-tensors-of-a-single-element-can-be-converted-to-an-index/45641/2), the following line works.

```
f = e[:d.to(dtype=torch.long)]
```

However, the gradients are lost. Is there someway I can pass the gradients or this operation is not differentiable at all? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't backprop through the index values of a slice. You can only backprop through the tensor being sliced.

If you want selection to be learned, you need to have a "soft" selection method. You can do this with the gumbel softmax reparameterization trick

```py
e = torch.arange(10) # the tensor we want to select from
logits = torch.randn(e.shape, requires_grad=True) # selection logits, predicted by model

soft_selection = F.softmax(logits, dim=0) # soft selection weights

selection_index = soft_selection.argmax() # index we want to select
hard_selection = torch.zeros_like(logits) # selection mask
hard_selection[selection_index] = 1. # add 1 at selection index

# this passes the soft_selection through the hard_selection tensor
hard_selection = hard_selection - soft_selection.detach() + soft_selection

selection = e * hard_selection # selection via multiplication 

selection.backward(gradient=torch.ones_like(selection)) # example backprop

assert logits.grad is not None # gradients have been passed through
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know. Just curious, are you one of the developers of PyTorch? You can choose to not answer :)

Comment: Okay, as far as I understand, the assumption here is that the selection logits is a vector. But as you can see from my example above, the variable `d` is a scalar tensor with gradients. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You can't backprop through indexing in the way you want. To do what you want, you need to reframe your problem in a way that is more "learnable" in a ML context. This question and your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78072628/pass-gradients-through-min-function-in-pytorch) both deal with trying to apply gradient based learning to "hard" operations like `min` or indexing. You'll have more success in solving your problem if you can reframe it in terms of "soft" operations. Gumbel softmax is one example of doing this

Answer (score 0):

As is, the operation is not differentiable.
Think about the definition of the gradient:

```
                     e[:(d+eps)] - e[:(d+eps)]
    df/dd  = limit       ------------
           eps->0              eps
```

So you would need to a define what it means to take "a little bit more of the e then d".

A common trick to do this is to soften the expression:
Instead of indexing you could multiply by a mask that is almost 1 for values below d and almost zero for values above d, with a smooth transition in between.
But this will always result in values in f that are not actually in e, but some interpolation or weighted values.

What do you want to achieve in the end?
Maybe there is another way that retains gradients?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I need to train the number of samples that it picks from the array `e`. In other words, I want to pick few elements of array `e`. How many elements are picked is what I want to train.